# How can I start using MLFlow on databricks with an existing trained model?

Tags: machine-learning, databricks, workflow, mlflow

I have an existing model that was trained on Azure. I want to fully integrate and start using the model on Databricks. Whats the best way to do this? How can I successfully load the model into databricks model workflow? I have the model in a pickle file

I have read almost all the documentation on databricks, but 99% of it is regarding new models trained on databricks and never about importing existing models.

Comment: What have you used to train the model? AzureML?

Comment: Yes, its also a sklearn model at its core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since MLFlow has a standardized [model storage format](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/models.html#storage-format), you just need to bring over the model files and start using them with the MLFlow package. In addition, you can register the model to the workspace's model registry using `mlflow.register_model()` and then use it from there. These would be the steps:

1. On the AzureML side, I assume that you have an MLFlow model saved to disk (using `mlflow.sklearn.save_model()` or `mlflow.sklearn.autolog` -- or some other `mlflow.<flavor>`). That should give you a folder that contains an `MLModel` file, and, depending on the flavor of the model a few more files -- like the below:

```
mlflow-model
├── MLmodel
├── conda.yaml
├── model.pkl
└── requirements.txt
```

> Note: You can download the model from the AzureML Workspace using the
> [v2 CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-configure-cli?tabs=public) like so: `az ml model download  --name <model_name> --version <model_version>`

2. Open a Databricks Notebook and make sure it has `mlflow` installed

```py
%pip install mlflow
```

3. Upload the MLFlow model files to the `dbfs` connected to the cluster
   [image]
4. In the Notebook, register the model using MLFlow (adjust the `dbfs:` path to the location where the model was uploaded to).

```py
import mlflow

model_version = mlflow.register_model("dbfs:/FileStore/shared_uploads/mlflow-model/", "AzureMLModel")
```

Now your model is registered in the Workspace's model registry like any model that was created from a Databricks session. So, you can access it from the registry like so:

```py
model = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(f"models:/AzureMLModel/{model_version.version}")

input_example = {
   "sepal_length": [5.1,4.8],
   "sepal_width": [3.5,4.4],
   "petal_length": [1.4,2.0],
   "petal_width": [0.2,0.1]
 }
model.predict(input_example)
```

[image]

Or use the model as a `spark_udf`:

```py
import pandas as pd
model_udf = mlflow.pyfunc.spark_udf(spark=spark, model_uri=f"models:/AzureMLModel/{model_version.version}", result_type='string' )
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(input_example))
spark_df = spark_df.withColumn('foo', model_udf())
display(spark_df)
```

[image]

> Note that I am using `mlflow.pyfunc` to load the model since every
> MLFlow model needs to support the `pyfunc` flavor. That way, you don't
> need to worry about the native flavor of the model.

Answer (score 3):

1. If your source model is already in a MLflow tracking server.

https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow-export-import

2. If your source model was not trained in MLflow.

How do I create an MLflow run from a model I have trained elsewhere?

https://github.com/amesar/mlflow-resources/blob/master/MLflow_FAQ.md#how-do-i-create-an-mlflow-run-from-a-model-i-have-trained-elsewhere